# How can I throw a custom exception from Volley's onResponse and onErrorResponse methods

Tags: android, exception, android-volley

I have code that accesses an API which returns a series of geopoints for plotting a cycling route. As such, I first fetch the JSON object, then translate it to plottable points. I have an APIGenericException for all Exceptions relating to this API and I want to throw an APiRequestException (Which is a subclass of APIGenericException), if the request to the API is unsuccessful. I cannot figure out how to throw this as the onErrorResponse() method by Volley does not throw an exception. In addition to this, convertResponseToWayPoints also throws an exception, but I'm not sure how to pass that up to the onResponse and onto the requestRouteFromAPI method.

```
 public void requestRouteFromAPI(Context mainActivityContext, final String url) throws APIGenericException {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mainActivityContext);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                convertResponseToWayPoints(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                // TODO: Handle error
                Log.e("ERROR", "Error occurred ", error);
                throw new APiRequestException(url);
            }
        });      queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have a solution, but I'm not 100% sure based on not understanding how Volley's request operates. If the request is synchronous, would this be a way of approaching the issue? By adding a JSONObject that is assigned and then handling it outside the method.

```
private JSONObject APIrequestResponse;

public void getRoute(Context mainActivityContext) throws CycleStreetsException {
            requestRouteFromCycleStreets(mainActivityContext, getAPIURL());
            if(APIrequestResponse == null){
                throw new CycleStreetsRequestException(getAPIURL());
            }
            else{
                //make routes
            }
    }

public void requestRouteFromAPI(Context mainActivityContext, final String url) throws APIGenericException {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mainActivityContext);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                APIrequestResponse = response;
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                // TODO: Handle error
                Log.e("ERROR", "Error occurred ", error);
                APIrequestResponse = null;
            }
        });      queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);}
```